# Can't consume messages from Google PubSub emulator using .net client sdk

Tags: c#, google-cloud-pubsub, google-cloud-pubsub-emulator

After starting the Google PubSub emulator and sending some messages to it, I start the System Under Test and when I try to start the SubscriberClient, I get an exception:

```
Grpc.Core.RpcException
  HResult=0x80131500
  Message=Status(StatusCode="NotFound", Detail="Subscription does not exist (resource=franchisingSalesReceipts-motorpromo-sub-dl)", DebugException="Grpc.Core.Internal.CoreErrorDetailException: {"created":"@1635433978.567000000","description":"Error received from peer ipv4:127.0.0.1:8085","file":"..\..\..\src\core\lib\surface\call.cc","file_line":1067,"grpc_message":"Subscription does not exist (resource=franchisingSalesReceipts-motorpromo-sub-dl)","grpc_status":5}")
  Source=Google.Cloud.PubSub.V1
  StackTrace:
   at Google.Cloud.PubSub.V1.SubscriberClientImpl.SingleChannel.HandleRpcFailure(Exception e)
   at Google.Cloud.PubSub.V1.SubscriberClientImpl.SingleChannel.HandlePullMessageData(Task`1 moveNextTask)
   at Google.Cloud.PubSub.V1.SubscriberClientImpl.SingleChannel.<>c__DisplayClass46_0.<HandlePullMoveNext>b__1()
   at Google.Cloud.PubSub.V1.SubscriberClientImpl.SingleChannel.<StartAsync>d__38.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Google.Cloud.PubSub.V1.Tasks.ForwardingAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Google.Cloud.PubSub.V1.Tasks.Extensions.<>c__DisplayClass4_0.<<ConfigureAwaitHideErrors>g__Inner|0>d.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at PromotionEngine.OneToOne.Infrastructure.Services.GooglePubSubConsumerService.<RegisterEventHandler>d__6`2.MoveNext() in C:\Users\jmourao\workspace\MotorPromocao\PromotionEngine.OneToOne\src\PromotionEngine.OneToOne.Infrastructure\Services\GooglePubSubConsumerService.cs:line 57

  This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:
    [External Code]
    PromotionEngine.OneToOne.Infrastructure.Services.GooglePubSubConsumerService.RegisterEventHandler<TWorker, TMessage>(string) in GooglePubSubConsumerService.cs
```

REPRO STEPS

After starting the emulator using this command:

```
gcloud beta emulators pubsub start --project=integracao-apigee-dev
```

I connect a publisher using something like this:

```cs
public GcpEmulatorPublisherService(
            ILogger<GcpEmulatorPublisherService> logger,
            IConfiguration config)
        {
            _logger = logger;

            string endpoint = config.GetValue<string>("GoogleCloudPubSub:host");
            string projectId = config.GetValue<string>("GoogleCloudPubSub:projectId");
            string[] topics = config.GetSection("GoogleCloudPubSub:topics").Get<string[]>();
            string currentTopicId = config.GetValue<string>("GoogleCloudPubSub:currentTopicId");

            PublisherServiceApiClient publisherService = new PublisherServiceApiClientBuilder
            {
                Endpoint = endpoint,
                ChannelCredentials = ChannelCredentials.Insecure
            }.Build();

            foreach (string topicId in topics)
            {
                TopicName topicName = new TopicName(projectId, topicId);
                try
                {
                    publisherService.CreateTopic(topicName);
                }
                catch (RpcException ex) when (ex.StatusCode == StatusCode.AlreadyExists)
                {
                    _logger.LogInformation($"Topic already exists: ProjectId {projectId} TopicId {topicId}");
                }
            }

            var settings = new PublisherClient.ClientCreationSettings(
                credentials: ChannelCredentials.Insecure,
                serviceEndpoint: endpoint
            );

            _publisherClient = PublisherClient.Create(new TopicName(projectId, currentTopicId), settings);
        }
```

After that, I just start my **system under test** with the Insecure credentials and localhost ServiceEndpoint:

```cs
SubscriberClient.ClientCreationSettings clientCreationSettings = new(clientCount: 1, credentials: ChannelCredentials.Insecure, serviceEndpoint: "localhost:8085");

var subscriberClient = await SubscriberClient.CreateAsync(subscription, clientCreationSettings);
```

Everything ok until here.

When I try to start the subscription like this:

```cs
await subscriberClient.StartAsync(async (PubsubMessage message, CancellationToken cancellationToken) =>
                {
                    try
                    {
                        TMessage messageBody = ConvertMessageBody<TMessage>(message);
                        TWorker worker = DependencyResolver.GetRequiredService<TWorker>();
                        await worker.ProcessAsync(messageBody);
                        return await Task.FromResult(SubscriberClient.Reply.Ack);
                    }
                    catch (Exception exception)
                    {
                        string exceptionMessage = string.Format(
                            "Exception reading message from subscription from supplier {0}. See inner exception for details. Message={1}",
                            topicName, exception.Message);
                        Exception trackedException = new(exceptionMessage, exception);
                        _telemetryWrapper.TrackException(trackedException);
                        _logger.LogError(trackedException, "Error processing message");
                        return await Task.FromResult(SubscriberClient.Reply.Nack);
                    }
                }).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

I get the afore mentioned exception.

Comment: Which line in the code caused the error?

Comment: await subscriberClient.StartAsync(...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out what was causing the issue.

I didn't create the Subscription I was trying to use with my System Under Test (consumer).

I was not aware that you have to create a Topic and a Subscription so that the consumer application can use this subscription to receive the messages.

So in my Publisher test application, I am creating the subscriptions needed just like in the documentation:

```cs
// Subscribe to the topic.
SubscriberServiceApiClient subscriberService = await SubscriberServiceApiClient.CreateAsync();
SubscriptionName subscriptionName = new SubscriptionName(projectId, subscriptionId);
subscriberService.CreateSubscription(subscriptionName, topicName, pushConfig: null, ackDeadlineSeconds: 60);
```

I also found out that if you try to create a subscription using the subscriptionId equal the topicId, it won't work.